# How to setup CruiseControl.NET with MSTest running Selenium Webdriver unit tests?

Tags: selenium, msbuild, webdriver, mstest, cruisecontrol.net

I've been looking for a while for a step by step instruction or examples of how setting up CruiseControl.NET with MSTest works, but with no actual luck. This is where I'm hoping someone might be able to help and point me in the right direction. I'm sure this has been asked loads of times but from searching I couldn't find my answer.

```
        <exec>    
      <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</executable>
      <baseDirectory>D:\<project>\celeriac\Pumpkin.Selenium\bin\Debug</baseDirectory>
      <buildArgs>
        /testcontainer:Pumpkin.Selenium.dll
        /test:<testName>
        /runconfig:localtestrun.Testrunconfig
        /resultsfile:testResults.trx
      </buildArgs>
      <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    </exec>
```

I've added the above to my ccnet.config file after the MSBuild (which works fine) but running the tests after the build is complete doesn't work.

I not 100% if the basedirectory looks correct? or I need something else in the buildargs?

If I run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 it works fine and runs my selenium webdriver tests, so I'm not sure what I'm missing? Heres is the snippit from the command prompt.

```
D:\<project>\celeriac\Pumpkin.Selenium\bin\Debug>MSTest /testcontainer:Pum
```

pkin.Selenium.dll /test:

Thanks in advance for any help.

I've now managed to get this to work.

I needed to create a batch file with the build args to run the desired tests and to delete any existing trx files. then save locally the drivers on the build server itself.

testResults.bat - del testResults.trx
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:Pumpkin.Selenium.dll /category:"Regression" /resultsfile:testResults.trx

this was then saved in the following location of D:\CruiseControl\testProject\Pumpkin.Selenium\bin\Debug\RunTests.bat        and called in the ccnet.config file of the build project.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: I get the loading dll message, followed by the tests running but with errors. The actual error message I don't know. I think its because the build server doesn't know what to do with the selenium tests and fails. Sorry for being vague but not sure where to look to find a more detailed error message from the cruisecontrol.net dashboard.

Comment: Possible issue can be url not needs to point to correct env. If local build then needs to be localhost?
Does it need permission to interact with the machine?
SeleniumRC/Grid To run remotely?

Comment: a good blog to check out - https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/bm-bloggers/post/2006/06/14/MSTest-and-CruiseControl-NET-.aspx